# typing effect in Arabic language appear disconnected

Tags: javascript, arabic, typeit

So I used this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp) to make a typing effect and it appears great in English, I tried
to use Arabic text (which is a connected letter language) and it appears good on my device.

when I sent the app prototype for the client to test it, the Arabic language letters appear disconnected in his device! so weird as I couldn't debug it because it does not happen on my laptop and mobile phone!

I found this [library](https://typeitjs.com/) which has a test demo at the bottom of the page, I asked him to test Arabic words on it, it appears like this on his device (iPhone xs max, chrome browser):

[image: client device]

but it appears like this on my device (Linux, chrome browser):

[image]

any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to set `dir` attribute on the element `rtl`?

Comment: Is the problem is with all arabic text or specific when you render it letter by letter ?

Comment: @tawfiknasser when render it letter by letter.

Comment: @AlanOmar yes, no luck.

Comment: @AlanOmar and you used innerHTML same as the tutorial ?

Comment: @tawfiknasser I used the jquery `append(text.charAt(i))`

Comment: @tawfiknasser you were right, the issue was because I used append, using native innerHTML fixed it. please make it an answer so that I can accept it